# Pronunciation of mathematical terms "Mahlo cardinal" and "mahloness" by native English speakers

Tags: pronunciation, nouns, loan-words

There are terms [*Mahlo cardinal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahlo_cardinal) and *mahloness* used in set theory (a branch of mathematics). These terms originated from the name of [Friedrich Paul Mahlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Mahlo), a German mathematician. I've only ever seen them in print and never actually heard anybody saying them.

So, I'm interested to know how these terms are usually pronounced by mathematicians who are native English speakers. In particular, what exactly sounds correspond to letters *ah* in *Mahlo* and on which syllable the stress is placed? The pronunciation written in [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) or a link to an audio/video where I could listen to it would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I would say that in mathematics it's fairly common to attempt to preserve the pronunciation in the original language when carrying it to English - e.g., Euler, Gauss - but of course, the difference in commonly used sounds between the languages causes some deterioration in the pronunciation. I would hazard a guess at mä-ˈlō (disclaimer: I don't know IPA; I copied these from mah-jong & hello), but without knowing the German pronunciation - and without having encountered this term before - I can't offer a concrete answer. Perhaps posting in math.SE or MO.SE may be more fruitful.

Comment: It's a German name, so /'maːloː/.

Comment: Found this: http://www.pronouncekiwi.com/Mahlo%20cardinal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IPA is [ˈmɑːlʌw] and rhymes with *swallow* , at least as pronounced in Standard American English.

Comment: If you're using rhyme, you should specify a dialect. I highly doubt that it rhymes with _swallow_ as it's pronounced by all speakers in the USA, or in Australia, or the UK.

Comment: I purposely chose swallow because it's pronounced the same, or close enough, in all varieties of English, as opposed to my first choice: hollow.

Comment: I'd say that [these elicitations are different](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/british/swallow_6), and that using the British pronunciation of swallow would make the name rhyme with "hollow", which I'm sure is not what you want.